# Adding a new 'li' each time a user enters in text and hits the button

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#btn1').click(function() {
 $('li').after($( "#txt1" ).val());
});
});
```

This works to add the text after the first li but when I enter in new text, it places it inside the same li - The question is: How do I get the jquery code to work to enter in a new li each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following updated code with fiddle should work much more smooth.

You should use a parent element for `li`, so that you can use `.append()` function

[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sykkadfk/7/)

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>ok</li>
    <li>ok</li>
    <li>ok</li>
    <li>ok</li>
</ul>
<input id="txt1" /><input type="submit" id="btn1">
```

**JQUERY CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn1').click(function() {
        //$('li').last().after('<li>' + $( "#txt1" ).val() + '</li>');
        $("ul").append("<li>"+$("#txt1").val()+"</li>");
        $("#txt1").val("").focus();//This will clear previous text and set focus
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks!! This was exactly what I was looking for. Now, I know there is a way to bring over css, but for the life of me I can't figure it out. do you add it to the button function or is it separate?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you are willing to do :

http://jsfiddle.net/sykkadfk/5/

You need to append `<li> & </li>` as told by @Tushar, but also, select only the `last()` element of `li`, please check the link above for demo.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn1').click(function() {
        $('li').last().after('<li>' + $( "#txt1" ).val() + '</li>');
    });
});
```